# Graphs not showing with Jinja, Flask, and CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, canvasjs

I am trying to get data from an API, pass it to the template with `Jinja`, and chart the data using `CanvasJS`.

When using baked in values, like in the `CanvasJS` examples, the graph displays properly; however, the second I try to use `Jinja` to input the values, the chart fails to show.

One reasons for the extra code, is that the API returns date in a "YYYY-MM-DD" form, whereas `JS` requires the individual values, so I split them using Jinja. Perhaps, I could split them using JS instead.

My `CanvasJS` code + `Jinja` looks like this:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        title:{
            text: "{{ ticker_symbol }}"
        },
        zoomEnabled: true,
        axisY: {
            includeZero:false,
            title: "Prices",
            prefix: "$ "
        },
        axisX: {
            interval:2,
            intervalType: "month",
            valueFormatString: "MMM-YY",
            labelAngle: -45
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "candlestick",
            dataPoints: [
            {% for key, value in data.items() %}
                {% set dates = key.split("-") %}
                {x: new Date({{ dates[0] }}, {{ dates[1] }}, {{ dates[2] }}]),y:[{{ value['1. open'] }}, {{ value['2. high'] }}, {{ value['3. low'] }}, {{ value['4. close'] }}]},
            {% endfor %}
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
```

The data is making it to the page, is displayed in the `JS` when viewing the source of the file in situ.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        title:{
            text: "MSFT"
        },
        zoomEnabled: true,
        axisY: {
            includeZero:false,
            title: "Prices",
            prefix: "$ "
        },
        axisX: {
            interval:2,
            intervalType: "month",
            valueFormatString: "MMM-YY",
            labelAngle: -45
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "candlestick",
            dataPoints: [


                {x: new Date(2019, 11, 15]),y:[148.9300, 149.9900, 148.2700, 149.9700]},
                ...(repeated)...
        ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
```

But the graph still does not show!

I'm sure there is an issue with how the data is parsed into `JS`, but I am unable to spot it. One thing I noticed, is that the last date value is accompanied by an annoying "]" that does not seem to want to go away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one major issue:

I had an extra `]` when setting the `x:` variable for the chart. This is the primary thing that broke the entire graph.

The Jinja was fine. The JS was fine. My inability to hit `{{ }}` without making a square bracket was the issue.

Please commence public flogging.